# locationmanager not stopping without using the navigationback button

Tags: cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

In my iphone application i m tracking userlocation in background for every one minute.For that i m using uiswitch.with help of that i m start/stop the background process.when i m in that trackingoption page the start and stop perfectly start and stop the background service.If i go to another page with that service start status i cant stop that service..that background service is going....but with navigationcontroller back button i came to that page means it is working..so i m confused where i missed that..please help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)_stopLocation
{
    if (__locationStarted) {
        if (![self isLocationServicesEnabled]) {
            return;
        }

        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        __locationStarted = NO;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    [self _stopLocation];
}
```

Comment: thanks..but i cant understand this..can u give some explanation

Comment: -(IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender{
    if(startTrackingButton.on){
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:startTrackingButton.on forKey:@"switchValue"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else{
       
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        
    }
}

Comment: in your code.what is __locationStarted and isLocationServicesEnabled

Comment: damm even I post a fully code as novice develeppel can't gues what can be those 2 wariable....  if (__locationStarted) than   __locationStarted what wariable is that?